# Can I deduce the return type of a lambda without actually calling it?

Tags: c++11, lambda, type-deduction

It might seem obvious to some, but I was still wondering: is there no way to make the compiler deduce the lambda return type without actually calling it?

Of course you can `auto retval = myLambda();`, however I want sth like:

```
T_MY_LAMBDA_RETVAL retval;
...
retval = myLambda();
```

Why would I want that? Simple:

```
try {
    auto retval = myLambda();
catch (exception e) {
    ...
}

// retval is undefined but I wonna have it!!! :)
```

Comment: `// retval is undefined but I wonna have it!!! :)`. What. How exactly do you want to access a variable beyond its scope?

Comment: @William Andrew Montgomery: obviously by forward declaring retval which is the whole purpose of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef typename std::result_of<decltype(lambda)()>::type return_type;
```

deduces the return type of invoking `lambda` with 0 arguments.

As would:

```
typedef decltype( lambda() ) return_type;
```

Be careful about possible rvalue references.

Answer (score 3):

To complete Yakk's answer

with:

```
auto myLambda = [&](int) { return 42; }; // Or any lambda
```

you may use

```
using T_MY_LAMBDA_RETVAL = std::result_of<decltype(myLambda)(int)>::type;
```

or

```
using T_MY_LAMBDA_RETVAL = decltype(myLambda(std::declval<int>()));
```

and then use it:

```
T_MY_LAMBDA_RETVAL retval;
try {
    retval = myLambda(42);
catch (exception& e) {
    // ...
}
// you may use retval which may be uninitialized.
```

Answer (score 0):

A lambda expression creates a unique functor type that overloads `operator()`, this is what gets invoked when you call the lambda. We can make use of this fact to figure out the return type of the lambda expression.

```
template<typename T>
struct lambda_traits_helper;  // undefined

// specialize for pointer to member function
template<typename T, typename Result, typename... Args>
struct lambda_traits_helper<Result(T::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using result_type = Result;
};

template<typename Func>
struct lambda_traits 
    : lambda_traits_helper<decltype(&Func::operator())>
    // instantiate helper trait with pointer to operator()
{};
```

Example usage:

```
auto lambda = []{ return 42; };
assert((std::is_same<int, lambda_traits<decltype(lambda)>::result_type>::value));

auto lambda = [](int a){ return std::to_string(a); };
assert((std::is_same<std::string, lambda_traits<decltype(lambda)>::result_type>::value));
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/253b35d90db5e73f)

Comment: In C++1y `auto lambda = []( auto&& x ) { return x; };` will cause problems with this technique, so I'd advise against it.